# Elements with a height of 0 are still considered visible. Are there alternative solutions?

Tags: jquery

The jQuery docs say the following:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or **height that is greater than zero.**

But the following code doesn't seem to follow that rule. I have a list with a height of 0 and I'm searching for an item inside the last visible list, but the list with the height of 0 is still being selected.

What are some ways to select items that have a height greater than 0?

Update:

The hidden class is applied in other ways in my project. I don't have access to a class which toggles height, which is why I need to check the height instead.

---

Note: In the below code, I'm aware of the overlapping text. I left it there to demonstrate that the list with a height of 0 is still being selected.

```js
// Attempt 1
// var $focusItem = $('ul:visible').find('li:last').find('a');

// Attempt 2
var $focusItem = $($('ul').not('ul[style*="height: 0"]')).find('li:last').find('a');

$focusItem.focus();
```

```css
.hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Button 1 </a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <!-- li:last -->
            <a href="#">Focus Me</a> <!-- desired focused item -->
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Don't Focus Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Don't Focus me</a> <!-- actual focused item -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want to hide it, why not make it display none?

Comment: This list has CSS transitions and display none would cause problems when hiding a list. I would have to wait for the transition to finish before hiding the list. Checking for height would be a simpler than checking when an animation has ended - I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why jquery works as it works, but what you can do is to use filter:

```
$focusItem = $("ul").filter(function() {
return $(this).height() >0 ;
}).find('li:last').find('a');
```

P.S. The selector with 'style' would work if you had an in-line style.

Comment: Ah, thanks for showing me how else I could use filter. I didn't know you could pass it a function like that. I like this answer and it makes sense, but I couldn't get it to work. It gives me the same results. I've simplified the example above.

Comment: @Dustin due to your nested structure, I have tried a lot of different selectors but the only way I found it to be working is to set the bg again after your first statement

Comment: @Dustin The problem is that the very first ul passes the filter, if you change the first selector to `$("ul ul")` is should work

Comment: With some tweaks, I think I can make this work. I think filter is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! To filter out all outer lists you can try using `return $(this).height() >0 && !$(this).find('ul').length ;` in the filter. It's a somewhat more robust solution than selecting 'ul ul ul' :)

Answer (score 1):

Root issue is your selector `$('ul').not('ul[style*="height: 0"]')` will get all of the `li` because your first `ul` is visible

Updated

You can do something like

http://jsfiddle.net/4dhqhe82/1/

```
$focusItem = $("ul ul > li > ul").filter(function () {
    return $(this).height() > 0;
}).find('li:last').find('a');
```

Again, this isn't robust but works for your current code. If you can add a class or two in the html structure it would make this a lot easier

Comment: I've simplified my example. Sorry about the lists. I admit that was kind of a mess. The orange was just to help me visualize what code I was running, but I've removed it. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Dustin I have seen it and the answer is still the same. The thing is when you do something like `ul:visible li:last` this will target all of the `li` in your current code and it will set the colour from that. The rest of the matched elements don't even matter

Comment: I don't actually have access to the hidden class. The update to my question was to clarify why I need to check the height instead.

Comment: So the height = 0 is applied on the element as inline css? Through js I guess

Comment: Through CSS descendant selectors from multiple parent elements with toggled classes. I don't have much control over those.